# How to iterate list of Charmaps in charmap.All and compare names?

Tags: go, text, encoding, charmap

I'd like to write a little command-line utility to decode/encode streams of text, like `iconv`, but in Go.  The user will provide the encoder and decoder names and the utility will check them against `charmap.All` to make the user args are valid before trying to decode/encode the stream.

I can iterate `charmap.All` and print the names like:

```golang
for _, cmap := range charmap.All {
    fmt.Println(cmap)
}
```

I can compare my `cmap` var to a known **Charmap**:

```golang
if cmap == charmap.ISO8859_1 {
    fmt.Println(charmap.ISO8859_1.String())
}
```

But I don't know how to do the next step, which seems so tantalizingly close (and easy):

```golang
var encoder string
flag.StringVar(&encoder, "encoder", "ISO 8859-1", "name of encoder")
flag.Parse()

for _, cmap := range charmap.All {
    if cmap.String() == encoder {
        // encode based on user's input
    }
}
```

Is that possible, given the **encoding/charmap** API?

Also, how is it that my `cmap` var and `charmap.ISO8859_1` are equivalent (in the `cmap == charmap.ISO8859_1` example), but `cmap` is really an **Encoding** interface, and I cannot convert:

`charmap.Charmap(cmap).String()` → `cannot convert cmap (type encoding.Encoding) to type charmap.Charmap`

I'm still pretty new to Go, and don't fully understand these differences and equivalencies in types and interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can break it down as follows, [charmap.All](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/text/+/refs/tags/v0.3.7:encoding/charmap/charmap.go;l=61) is a slice of [Encoding](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7/encoding#Encoding) interfaces, which can be iterated using a `range` loop.

The equality works because the type [Charmap](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/text/+/refs/tags/v0.3.7:encoding/charmap/tables.go;l=2288;drc=18b340fc7af22495828ffbe71e9f9e22583bc7a9), implements the interface, i.e. each charmap type will have a `NewDecoder()` and a `NewEncoder()` method implementation defined. By the language specification, if a struct implements an interface, they can be compared (See [Comparison operators](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators))

> A value x of non-interface type X and a value t of interface type T are comparable when values of type X are comparable and X implements T. They are equal if t's dynamic type is identical to X and t's dynamic value is equal to x

With the above inference, we can understand that the [func (*Charmap) String](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap#Charmap.String) is a method on the `Charmap` struct type and not on the interface. So the right way to do this, would be to [Type assert](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) your interface value and then call the string function on the same.

```golang
for _, enc := range charmap.All {
    cmap, ok := enc.(*charmap.Charmap)
    if ok && cmap.String() == encoder {
        // encode based on user's input
    }
}
```